# how to Resize Textbox while dragging it in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how to Resize Textbox while dragging it in asp.net? in run-time...

Comment: run-time or design-time? if either, why to do 2 operations in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery to your project and use one of plugins. [This](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer) for example.